# Flutter Compass Lagging on android. Anyone who can help me fix this lag?

Tags: javascript, php, flutter

I recently added a compass in my Flutter App.
It has been super laggy on android and i dont know the reason.
Can anyone help me fix this lag?

Was expecting a smooth result but it turned out to be super laggy.
i heard it works smoothly in iphones but lags on android devices.
i used the following dependency:

```
flutter_compass: ^0.7.0
```

```
  bool _hasPermissions = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchPermissionStatus();
  }

  void _fetchPermissionStatus() {
    Permission.locationWhenInUse.status.then((status) => {
          if (mounted)
            {
              setState(() {
                _hasPermissions = (status == PermissionStatus.granted);
              })
            }
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        if (_hasPermissions) {
          return _buildCompass();
        } else {
          return _buildPermissionSheet();
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  //permission widget
  Widget _buildPermissionSheet() {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Request Permission'),
        onPressed: () {
          Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().then((value) {
            _fetchPermissionStatus();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

//compass widget
Widget _buildCompass() {
  return StreamBuilder<CompassEvent>(
      stream: FlutterCompass.events,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          Text('Error Reading Heading :${snapshot.error}');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
        double? direction =snapshot.data!.heading;
        if(direction==null){
          return Center(child: Text('Device does not have sensors'),);
        }
        //return compass
        return Center(child:
          Container(child:
            Transform.rotate(
              angle: direction*(math.pi/180)*-1,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/ compass.png',height: 400,)),),);
      });
}
```

Comment: this is happen all devices or only one device?

Comment: on android devices.

Comment: One problem I could see is that Image.asset is not const. Can you try 
`child: const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/ compass.png', height: 400),)` ?